# Deshabilitar ventana chrome en selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, chromedriver

Necesito desactivar la ventana del navegador que se abre cuando se ejecutan los test. Copio el código que uso y debería funcionar pero no lo hace:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

def test(self):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Utilizo:

Python **3.5**

Chromedriver **2.35**

Google Chrome **64.0.3282.167**

Selenium **3.9.0**

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Tengo la version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit)..

Comment: Ahí cambie el código, funcionó. Si querés ponŕ el comentario como respuesta así lo marco como correcto. Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente las opciones que se le pasan a Chrome a través de `webdriver` no deben llevar el `--` delante. Además, en [otros](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-headless-chrome-with-selenium) [lugares](https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/) he visto que se instancia de forma diferente el objeto `options`.

Prueba a hacerlo como en los tutoriales que he enlazado, es decir:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):        
    def test(self):
        options = webdriver.chromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("headless")
        options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
        options.add_argument("no-sandbox")       
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```